# JHipster Angular use output of query as input of next query

Tags: angular, rxjs, jhipster

I am trying to write a code where an Angular Course Service receives the login id of a student to list all courses where the student enrolls. This result is then piped to another service which takes the output of the first query as its input.

```js
teachers: ITeacher[];
this.courseService.query({
  'stdId.equals': this.account?.login,
}).pipe(
  map(data=> {
    this.teacherService.query({
      'courseId.in': data.body, 
    }).subscribe((res: HttpResponse<ITeacher[]>) => {
      this.teachers = res.body;
    })
  })
);
```

The problem is that I am able to see the results in data.body, but I cannot get the actual values of the data. Eg. If I try to get the values as data.body.id, I get an error message saying there is no field id in the Class or Interface. I am new to Angular so these are my questions:

1. Is this the correct way to do what I am planning to do? If not, what is the correct way?
2. How do I get the values of the specific fields like id from the data.body?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the final aim of this Observable? In the snippet provided, you're not subscribing to it anywhere. Do you need the intermediate `data` from `courseService` or do you only need the final `this.teachers`? Either way I'd suggest changing the approach, but I need that info before making a recommendation.

Comment: I only need the teachers. But since there is no direct link between the student and the teachers, I have to go through the courses class to get to the teachers list.

Comment: Giving `map` a function of type `(v:any) => void` is generally a code smell. What are you mapping here?

Comment: As an alternative, it would be more efficient to create or modify a  RestController so that all the work is done on server in one request.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest that you use an Observable as your final "target". Instead of having `teachers` as a static array, you would have `teachers$`, an Observable, which you would consume in the DOM with the `async` pipe or elsewhere in your code. Also, you want to avoid subscribing to Observables inside Observable pipes (nested subscribe calls are BAD code smell).

Here is my suggested approach:

```js
teachers$: Observable<ITeacher[]>;
this.teachers$ = this.courseService.query({
  'stdId.equals': this.account?.login,
}).pipe(
  switchMap(data => this.teacherService.query({
    'courseId.in': data.body, 
  }))
);
```

When you need to subscribe to a child Observable from inside a parent Observable (like in this case), you should use a higher-order mapping operator like `switchMap`, `concatMap`, `mergeMap` or `exhaustMap`. These operators differ mostly in their concurrency models. For this case, depending on how many requests could potentially be made, you may want to change from `switchMap` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Embracing the suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69722929/2933780), I'd just add the solution to the array of course ids as follows:

```js
teachers$: Observable<ITeacher[]>;
this.teachers$ = this.courseService.query({
  'stdId.equals': this.account?.login,
}).pipe(
  map(data => data.body.map(({id}) => id)),
  map(data => this.teacherService.query({
    'courseId.in': data, 
  }))
);
```

I didn't test it but I think you can try this.